# Firebase deploy hosting path argument?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a site to a second firebase project, it kept deploying to the original so I ended up just deleting my .firebaserc and my firebase.json and starting fresh with `firebase init`. The generated .firebaserc and firebase.json don't seem to be working, when I run `firebase deploy` I get the following error:

`retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined`

I'm confused why it wouldn't work if it just generated the files anew. Does anyone know what could cause that?

Here's my .firebaserc:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "stage-striker-dev"
  }
}
```

and here's my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Running `firebase deploy --only hosting` gives the same result. I've also ran `npm install -g firebase-tools` to make sure I'm up to date.